# Why does EntityManager.merge() prevent LazyInitializationException while EntityManager.find() don't?

Tags: java, hibernate

Given the following situation in a web application:

```
// EntityManager em, one per Request with Spring's OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
// Parent oldParent, from previous request (and therefore another persistence context)
Parent parent = em.find(Parent.class, oldParent.getId());
List<Child> children = parent.getChildren(); // Mapped collection with LazyLoading
for (Child child : children) {
     ...
```

The call of the list iterator causes a `LazyInitializationException`. This is confusing, because the fetching of the list of children occurs in the same persistence context (or am i wrong?).
*But*, using `merge()`, it works. As if two request are sharing one persistence context.

```
Parent parent = em.merge(oldParent);
List<Child> children = parent.getChildren();
for (Child child : children) {
     ...
// No Exception!!
```

What is my error in reasoning?

**Addition**
I've proven that the error is not caused by `parent.getId()`. This is part of the stacktrace:

```
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.iterator(PersistentList.java:138)
```

That means it is actually the iterator that causes the problem. And it's getting even more weird - I've checked that in the first case (with `find()`), a select statement is issued by hibernate to retrieve a new object from the database, not from the cache of the persistence context.

**Addition2**
Here's a bit more stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: edeka.sw.phb.model.Chapter.subChapters, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.iterator(PersistentList.java:138)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1022)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1021)
    //... followed by the line of the foreach.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is not in the iterating part because you iterate with the new recently loaded parent.
The problem has to be with the .getId() that seems to not be loaded then the merge works because dont call the .getId()

Comment: Thanks lujop, but this is not the case. I am able the successfully get the id via `parent.getId()`, but the iteration fails. Please see my edits.

Comment: It's very strange. Can you put the detailed stacktrace? And the code is exactly what you put or you simplify it?

Comment: I added more stacktrace. I simplified the code a bit, but that should not matter.

Comment: A lot of times the devil is in the details. In the simplified code you put I didn't see any place where that error can happen in the iteration because you iterate with the recently attached parent and you haven't any code that closes the session.

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code either. Maybe the fetching the list of children does not occur in the same persistence context. How is your `em` initialized?